# iTerm2 output broken since upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm, tmux

Since I upgraded my OS X to El Capitan (10.11) the output of iTerm2 is completely messed up. See this example screenshot (iTerm2 on the left, Terminal.app on the right):

#### Update

I'm using iTerm 2.1.4 which should be the latest version.

[image: Left side is iTerm2, right side is Terminal.app].

The problem is independent from tmux, I just started it to show it's broken output.

I tried to play with `TERM` but without any luck. How to fix this?

Comment: Could you specify iterm2 version. Also, did you try with fresh preference settings (after saving old preference settings somewhere)?

Comment: @sdayal I *thought* that fresh settings had helped, but when I reapplied my settings (not by copying the back but by actual setting them) it came back.. Have to investigate which setting is causing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting that was causing the problem. I don't know why but its the "Treat ambiguous width-characters as double-width". See screenshot: [image] Disabling the setting makes the terminal work normal.

I'm using DejaVu Monospace for Powerline which might contain those ambiguous width character and I guess that the output of `doge` also contains those chars. So anyone using those should disable the setting.